# Erasing a first Instruction in Basic Block from LLVM IR?

Tags: llvm

I have the followint LLVM IR file

```
  %1 = load i32* %i, align 4
  %2 = load i32* %j, align 4
  %3 = icmp sgt i32 %1, %2
  br i1 %3, label %4, label %6

; <label>:4                                       ; preds = %0
  %5 = load i32* %i, align 4
  store i32 %5, i32* %k, align 4
  br label %6

; <label>:6                                       ; preds = %5, %0
  ret i32 0
```

In it I am first loading vairable "i" in %1 and variable "j" in %2 then I am comparing the greater than condition that is (i>j). Based on that there is branch either to label 4 or label 6. My problem is that there are two load instruction for variable "i" one in first basic block and other in 2nd basic block. Here I want to remove 2nd load instruction.
For it I am doing it as when I reach to 2nd load instruction for variable "i" I am replacing all uses of 2nd instruction by first instruction then I am erasing the current instruction i.e. 2nd. Here I am unable to set instruction iterator pointer. I do not want to set for next instruction(store i32 %5, i32* %k, align 4). Is there a other way?
If you know please let me know.

Comment: Not sure I understand your question. But I'm pretty sure that subsequent passes should be able to easily remove that load for you, so I wouldn't really bother. If you have a compelling reason to delete the load, please restate your question, for I'm unable to understand what your problem really is.

Comment: My problem is that after deleting the second load instruction I want to set instruction iterator such that in next iteration it should reach to (store i32 %5, i32* %k, align 4) because in for loop I am incrementing the instruction iterator.

Comment: Why not simply obtaining a new iterator by calling `BB->begin()` again immediately after the `inst->eraseFromParent()`?

Comment: Thanks a lot for your kind help, :)
Its working correctly. what a simple solution!

Comment: Thanks to your help. What you said is correct and its working correctly. My problem is solved!, :-)

Answer (score 12):

If I understand you correctly, all you want is just to erase an instruction and keep iterating over the code. If that's right, take a look at this example from the `DeadInstElimintation` pass (which lives in `lib/Transforms/Scalar/DCE.cpp`):

```
virtual bool runOnBasicBlock(BasicBlock &BB) {
  bool Changed = false;
  for (BasicBlock::iterator DI = BB.begin(); DI != BB.end(); ) {
    Instruction *Inst = DI++;
    if (isInstructionTriviallyDead(Inst)) {
      Inst->eraseFromParent();
      Changed = true;
      ++DIEEliminated;
    }
  }
  return Changed;
}
```

The interesting thing to note is how the iterator is incremented. The `DI++` is not done inside the last clause of the `for`, but rather separately, with the current `DI` assigned to `Inst`. This ensures that even if you delete `Inst`, `DI` already points to the next instruction so the loop will keep running over the next instructions.

Comment: I got a solution from CAFxX. Thanks to you also for your help.

Comment: @damrudhard: setting the new iterator to `BB->begin()` will only work if the new instruction is the first in the basic block. Otherwise you'll go back a few instructions. If this is OK with you, then no problem. I think the solution shown in my answer is more general, though.

Comment: In other case I am setting the instruction iterator to previous instruction so that in next iteration it will point to the instruction 
right after the deleted one.